# A function that detects whether a string contains an uppercase letter or not, and if so, converts it to a lowercase letter

Tags: c, ascii, c-strings

The following function works fine if the entire string consists of uppercase letters only, but does not for a string which consists of other characters too, such as "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama". In this case, every element is changed.

```
void UppercaseToLowercase(char arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) // i < size - 1 since last element is '\0'
    {
        if (65 <= arr[i] <= 90) // ASCII values for uppercase letters
            arr[i] += 32; // ASCII values for lowercase letters
    }
}
```

How can this be corrected?

Comment: Aside: There are functions in the ```ctype.h``` header file that automatically do these conversions for you, namely ```toupper```, ```tolower```, ```isupper```, ```islower``` etc.

Comment: Also, you should avoid magic numbers, instead, `if ('A'<= arr[i] && arr[i] <= 'Z')`

Comment: Calling tolower() on each character without testing for isupper/islower can be more performant.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is in the logic of your if statement.  Instead of

```
if (65 <= arr[i] <= 90)
```

A proper logical test for multiple conditions such as this would need to include the && conjunction.  With what you are attempting to test, the comparison test would be as follows.

```
if (65 <= arr[i] && arr[i] <= 90) // ASCII values for uppercase letters
```

When testing that out with a word such as "Panama" following was the result in a test program built to call your function.

```
@Dev:~/C_Programs/Console/CaseCheck/bin/Release$ ./CaseCheck 
Enter a word: Panama
Before: Panama
After: panama
```

The take-away from this issue is be cognizant of developing logic that have tests with multiple conditions that might require the && (and) conjunction or the || (or) conjunction.

Give that a try to see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: I suggest to explain what actually happens with `65 <= arr[i] <= 90` and why it is always true. The program would be easier to understand with character literals instead of numbers, e.g. `if (`'A' <= arr[i] && arr[i] <= 'Z')  arr[i] += ('a' - 'A');`. Or even better use the functions from `ctype.h`: `if(isupper(arr[i])) arr[i] = tolower(arr[i]);`. You should show the source code of your test program.

Answer (score 1):

`65 <= arr[i] <= 90` does not test whether `arr[i]` is between 65 and 90. Its grammatical structure is `(65 <= arr[i]) <= 90`. This means that first `65 <= arr[i]` is evaluated. If it is true, the resulting value is 1. If it is false, the resulting value is 0. Then this result, 0 or 1, is compared to `90`, as if it were `0 <= 90` or `1 <= 90`. Both of these are true, so the result is always true.

The test should be written as `65 <= arr[i] && arr[i] <= 90`. The grammatical structure of this is `(65 <= arr[i]) && (arr[i] <= 90)`. Each comparison is evaluated separately, and then their results are combined with `&&`.

Additionally, character constants should be used instead of numeric constants. The test can be written `'A' <= arr[i] && arr[i] <= Z'`, which makes its intent and meaning clearer. Similarly, `arr[i] += 32` should be written as `arr[i] += 'a' - 'A'`. Then this code will work for any character set in which the codes for the uppercase letters are consecutive from “A” to “Z” and the codes for the lowercase letters are also consecutive.

There are character sets in which they are not consecutive, and code like this should not be used for fully portable support. I presume this is for a school exercise, in which case it is okay. However, fully portable code should use the `isupper` and `tolower` functions declared in `<ctype.h>`.